# Why Can't I Call Two Aliases With ";"?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

When I try to combine two normal commands using the `;` character (eg. `ls; cd`) it works fine.  However, I have two aliases that I've created (`stopdev` and `startdev`), and if I try to combine them:

```
stopdev; startdev
```

or even if I just try and add a semi-colon after one:

```
stopdev;
```

I get a syntax error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

I also have the same problem if I use `&&`:

```
stopdev && startdev
```

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'

I'm confused by this because I had thought that aliases were just like any other commands ... but clearly they aren't.

So, two questions:

1. Why is using `;` or `&&` with an alias call invalid?
2. Is there any way (other than creating a `stopstartdev` alias) to easily run these two commands together?

Here's the definition of `stopdev`:

```
alias stopdev="cd $HOME/website; make website_stop; make backend_stop;"
```

Comment: They work fine on my system. Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly how the aliases are defined. Do you also have this with very simple aliases? Try running `alias a="echo foo"; alias b="echo bar"; a; b`. Does that work?

Comment: what are those aliases ? I mean when you say `stopdev`, what does the alias do ? I created 2 aliases to 2 simple commands and it works fine with a semicolon in between them

Comment: One of them is `alias stopdev="cd $HOME/website; make website_stop; make backend_stop;"`.  I think we've found the problem.  If either of you want to provide an answer to the effect of "it's because your alias has a semi-colon at the end of its definition, dummy" I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: P.S. Just to be clear for anyone reading this later, removing the semi-colon from the end of my alias's definition did in fact fix the problem.

Comment: You can remove the last `;` after backend_stop

Comment: P.P.S. And for anyone reading the above P.S., note that removing the last semi-colon is a bad idea as it will take any parameters fed to the alias and feed them to the `make backend_stop` command, as noted in [@Gilles' answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/266109/135943).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alias is expanded simply by replacing the alias by its definition (as a list of tokens, not a string, which is basically equivalent to taking the string and adding a space at the end). So `stopdev; true` is expanded to

```
cd $HOME/website; make website_stop; make backend_stop; ; true
                                                      ^^^
```

Since you can't have two consecutive semicolons in the shell syntax, that's a syntax error.

You can remove the `;`, and that will make `stopdev; startev` work, but it isn't good, because any argument you pass to `stopdev` will be passed to `make backend_stop`, which is probably not desirable.

You should make this a function. Also, don't run the `make` commands if the `cd` command fails.

```
stopdev () {
  cd "$HOME/website" && {
    make website_stop
    make backend_stop
  }
}
```

An improvement would be to make the function return a failure code even if `make website_stop` fails but `make backend_stop` succeeds.

```
stopdev () {
  cd "$HOME/website" && {
    make website_stop
    ret=$?
    make backend_stop && return $ret
  }
}
```

Note that this leaves you in the `~/website` directory. To avoid changing the directory of the shell process, run the function in a subshell.

```
stopdev () (
  cd "$HOME/website" && {
    make website_stop
    ret=$?
    make backend_stop && return $ret
  }
)
```

Alternatively, with GNU make, you can use its `-C` option.

```
stopdev () {
  make -C "$HOME/website" website_stop
  ret=$?
  make -C "$HOME/website" backend_stop && return $ret
}
```

If the targets never fail, just pass them both.

```
stopdev () (
  cd "$HOME/website" && make website_stop backend_stop
)
```

or

```
stopdev () {
  make -C "$HOME/website" website_stop backend_stop
}
```

Comment: Exhaustively good answer.

Comment: Does the subshell variation need curly braces for the function definition?

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, since it uses parentheses, precisely to make the body execute in a subshell.

Comment: I had this issue with `alias CLONE='nohup konsole --workdir "$(pwd)" &>/dev/null &'` and `alias REFRESH='CLONE; exit'`. This worked until recently on my bash. Removing the `;` makes it work again but I don't like that too much and dont understand how a backgrounding `&` stops me from following with `;`; is it actually the same issue, or just coincidentally the same solution?

Comment: @Hashbrown It's the same issue. The reason is that `&` and `;` in fact have the same role in the shell grammar: they terminate a simple command, and which one you use determines whether the command is executed in the foreground or in the background. They only appear to have different roles because semicolons are used rarely: usually they're conveyed by a newline, which means “if a command terminator is expected, pretend there was a `;`, else ignore the newline”. `alias REFRESH=$'CLONE\n exit'` should work in all bash versions except antique ones. Use an actual newline instead for portability.